# Changing font in CHOOSECOLOR dialog

Tags: windows, delphi, common-controls, colordialog

I'm using the Windows common controls [CHOOSECOLOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646912%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) dialog, but on Win 7 it sticks out like a sore thumb as it still uses the 'old' Tahoma font.

[image: ChooseColor Dialog]

Is there a fairly easy way of getting it to use Segoe UI or some other font?

If it matters, I'm using Delphi/C++Builder...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think it is a good idea to alter the default font, but sure, it's doable:

```
function EnumChildProc(hWnd: HWND; lParam: LPARAM): LongBool; stdcall;
begin
  SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETFONT, lParam, Integer(true));
  result := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.ColorDialogShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  dlg: TColorDialog;
begin
  if not (Sender is TColorDialog) then Exit;
  dlg := TColorDialog(Sender);

  SendMessage(dlg.Handle, WM_SETFONT, Self.Font.Handle, Integer(true));

  EnumChildWindows(dlg.Handle, @EnumChildProc, Self.Font.Handle);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TColorDialog.Create(nil) do
    try
      OnShow := ColorDialogShow;
      Execute(Handle);
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;
```

This will use the `Form1.Font` font.

[image: Color Dialog with custom font]

Still, in this case, I might just find it acceptable:

[image: Color Dialog with default font (Tahoma)] [image: Color Dialog with Segoe UI font]

Tahoma (Default) vs. Segoe UI

**But!** There are issues involved:

[image: Color Dialog with default font - no issues]

[image: Color Dialog with custom font causing issues]

The safest thing to do, I think, is not to alter the default (intended) appearance of the dialog. Then, at least, you can blame Microsoft for any scaling issues...